# Swift - WatchKit: Setting background color for selected row on table (WKInterfaceTable)

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos, wkinterfacetable

Swift - WatchKit: How to set background color for selected row on watch tables?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Make the background as Group

```
@IBOutlet weak var cellBackGroup: WKInterfaceGroup!
```

Then set

```
row.cellBackGroup.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.red)
```

You can keep a variable

```
var selectedIndex = 0
```

and implement delegate method

```
func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable,  didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int) {
    selectedIndex = rowIndex
    ....
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I know but how can I set color to only a cell that I select it?

Comment: se edit..........

Comment: Thanks; I made it, by help of you :)

Comment: @RezaKashkoul you may accept answer if helped